# Is there any program or add-ons to download FLV from website?

Tags: youtube, downloads, flv

I just need some sort of programs that can download flv from website like youtube and other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Video Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006/) is the best.

Comment: This has worked best for me too. They just need to make a Chrome extension now and I'm set. :)

Comment: I'm waiting for the Chrome extension too. Video Download Helper is really the best one out there.

Answer (score 1):

There is also youtube-dl. It's a command-line tool. The best feature of this tool is that it can accept a batch file as input. Besides this, it has many other features.

Be sure to install the latest stable version, not the one in the Software Center. Link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/youtube-dl_2011.08.04-1_all.deb

Sample working:

```
youtube-dl -ica http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1VezJENet8 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```