# How do I install Realplayer to download FLV files?

Tags: video, flash, downloads, video-player

I need to be able to download .flv (flash video), and I know that the program "Real Player" can easily do that. How can I install it? I cant find the installer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that installing an add-on in firefox. Don't need to install any program for that. Open firefox, go to the website with the flash video and click in download.

[Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) is the link to the add-on.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean downloading from youtube, you can install this extension[YouTube Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hokfcbmfpgeajcgkaeigohghnkhjmcbj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked. I have no idea how to merge post or something. But this is the link to the question and answer: [Is there any program or add-ons to download FLV from website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42642/is-there-any-program-or-add-ons-to-download-flv-from-website)